# Get value from load word that gives memory address

Tags: assembly, mips

so when I load word the value it gives me is a hex value that is supposed to be the address for the thing I want. How would I go to the address given to me.
Example:
lw $t0, 0($a0)

$t0 would give me 0x10010058 which is the memory address of the value I want, how would I go to mem address 0x10010058?

Comment: Use `$t0` as the address for another `lw`, obviously.  Look at C compiler output for a linked-list next function, for an example of pointer-chasing on MIPS.

Comment: You demonstrated that you know how load a word from an address stored in `$a0`. Shouldn't be that hard to figure out how to you load a word from an address stored in `$t0`. (I'm assuming you learned the `lw` instruction in general, not just the single specific instruction `lw $t0, 0($a0)`. If you're learning individual instructions once at a time, then it's going to be a long time before you learn all 4 billion instructions...)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "go to mem address", but if you want to access the value stored inside the mem address 0x10010058, you would just use sw register_to_store, 0(t0). this stores the value of the memory at the address t0 into the register. For instance, if you wanted to store the value to register t2, it would be sw, t2, 0(t0).

Of course, you have to call this after calling lw.